# Writing down solutions notation

Tags: notation

How do you write solutions to a simple equation in set notation?

For example:
- the solution to $x-4=0$
- the solutions to $x^2-x=0$?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: $\{x\mid f(x)=0\}$ is the set containing all solutions of equation $f(x)=0$.

Comment: Should I write $x \in {4}$ and $x \in {x | f(x)=0}?$

Comment: No. Set $\{x\mid x-4=0\}$ is the set containing exactly the solutions of equation $x-4$. In that sense the solutions of the equation are written in set notation, as you wanted. Here $y\in\{x\mid x-4=0\}$ means that $y-4=0$.

Comment: Brackets don't work, but ypu know what I mean.

Comment: Thanks so much! Another question: If I would want to write the solution in normal notation, would I write $x=1\vee x=0$ or $x=1\wedge x=0$

Comment: The first. $\vee$ stands for 'or'.

Answer (score 1):

You can write down the solutions both explicitly or implicitly, the latter uses the notation $\{x|\ldots\}$ or $\{x:\ldots\}$ which both means “the set of numbers $x$ such that $\ldots$ is true”. Here are some examples:

$$\begin{array}{c|c|c}
\text{Equations} &\text{(Implicit) Set of solutions} & \text{(Explicit) Set of solutions} \\ \hline
\overset{\displaystyle \color{white}d\,}{}3x+2=3x-1&\overset{\displaystyle \color{white}d\,}{}\{x:3x+2=3x-1\}& \varnothing \\
\sin x=-\sin(-x) &\{x:\sin x=-\sin(-x)\}&\mathbb R\\
x^2-3x=-2 &\{x\mid x^2-3x=-2\}& \{1,2\} \\ 
6x+15y=39 &\{(x,y)\mid 6x+15y=39\}&\left\{\left(x,\frac{13-2x}5\right)\,\left|\,\right.x\in\mathbb R\right\} \\ 
\end{array}$$

Answer (score 0):

If the solution to your equation is $a_{1},...a_{m}$ then in set
notation you simply write 
$$
\{a_{1},...,a_{m}\}
$$

in set notation

Answer (score 0):

Well, you can list the elements of the set of solutions:
For your two examples, you can use $\lbrace 4\rbrace$ and $\lbrace 0,1\rbrace$.